# Web Api Client - Consuming Service Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api control Method that returns db.Items data as follows.
The data is returned in JSON format.

```
public class ItemController : ApiController
{
    private SuperiorPizzaEntities db = new SuperiorPizzaEntities();

    // GET api/Item
    public IQueryable<Item> GetItems()
    {
       return db.Items;
    }

    More methods follow.
}
```

I want to consume this data in my C# console client.
What code needs to be written on my C# console client to do this please?

Comment: are you trying to test your service, is that why you are consuming from a console app?

Comment: You can use `RestSharp` and create a REST Call to this API from your console application.